# UIL Custom Downloader doesn't use content from cache

Tags: android, image, imageview, universal-image-loader

I've implemented an own Downloader but it seems he isn't using Images from the cache he already retrieved. My initialization:

```
private void initImageLoader() {
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this)
            .imageDownloader(new SocketDownloader(this))
            .memoryCacheSizePercentage(25)
            .writeDebugLogs()
            .build();
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
}
```

here is what i found in logcat:

```
01-10 11:47:26.899: D/ImageLoader(2345): Start display image task [socket://images/test-
icon-1.png_53x53]
01-10 11:47:26.899: D/ImageLoader(2345): Load image from network [socket://images/test-
icon-1.png_53x53]
01-10 11:47:26.899: D/Request(2345): request {"path":"images\/test-
icon-1.png","action":"getimage","actionid":0}
01-10 11:47:28.719: D/ImageLoader(2345): Subsample original image (200x200) to 100x100 
(scale = 2) [socket://images/test-icon-1.png_53x53]
01-10 11:47:28.729: D/ImageLoader(2345): ImageAware is reused for another image. Task is 
cancelled. [socket://images/test-icon-1.png_53x53]
01-10 11:47:28.839: D/ImageLoader(2345): Start display image task [socket://images/test-
icon-1.png_53x53]
01-10 11:47:28.839: D/ImageLoader(2345): Load image from network [socket://images/test-
icon-1.png_53x53]
01-10 11:47:28.839: D/Request(2345): request {"path":"images\/test-
icon-1.png","action":"getimage","actionid":0}
```

Runs on a nexus 7 which should have enough heap for this operation of 2 images actually. Thanks for replying with useful hints.

Comment: Did you enable caching in `DisplayImageOptions`?

Comment: This is my config:

    DisplayImageOptions opts = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .extraForDownloader(new      
    ImageSocketDownloaderExtra(request, actionId))
                .considerExifParams(false)
                .cacheInMemory()
                .build();

Answer (score 0):

As I see in logs the previous task was canceled during image loading. So image loading was interrupted because ImageView was reused. It seems you scroll list and `icon-1` go out of screen. Then you scroll and `icon-1` should be displayed again but it wasn't cached in memory because it wasn't downloaded fully (task was interrupted). So ImageLoader start loading again.
So it's ok.

BTW I recommend to enable caching on disk too. It prevents redundant downloads.